# bold/change text color in a workflow rule?

Tags: workflow, formula, html

i'm using a workflow rule to update a rich text field to be highlighted red (or just text red) and bold. and i'm struggling with how to get the html into the formula?

```
IF(STATUS == 'New', <html><body><div style="color: red;"><b>Urgent</b></div></body></html>')
```

any ideas how to execute this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below. if name is test then rich text field will be red otherwise green color.

```
IF(Name== 'test', '<html><body><div style="color: red;"><b>Urgent</b></div></body></html>', '<html><body><div style="color: green;"><b>Urgent</b></div></body></html>')
```

Comment: if i want the text to be just normal, no changes for the else, what should i put? thanks!

Comment: Remove style tag from div. It will work.